# Neo4j Cypher : How to set StartNode or endNode of a relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

Let's say we have two nodes n and m

Is it possible to set m as the startNode for all Relationship with n as the StartNode n-[r]->()

The relationships can have different types.

Is it possible using only one cypher request?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't re-assign the start node for a certain relationship.  What you can do is delete that relationship, and then create new ones that point where you want them to go.

For example:

```
MATCH (n { id: "startpoint"})-[r]->(), (m {id: "endpoint"})
MERGE (n)-[:newRelationship]->(m)
DELETE r;
```

This query would have to get much more complicated if the type of `:newRelationship` could change depending on `r`

Comment: Thanks. This query won't do the task as it would set m as the endNode instead of the StartNode. Anyway I am looking for a query that could take the type of the Relationship into account.

Comment: Could it be possible to set the type of a new Relationship based on the type of an existing Relationship, all in one cypher request?

Comment: No - again, you don't re-assign relationship types via cypher; you create the relationship of the right type that you need, and then you delete the old relationship type as appropriate.  I believe only properties and values of relationships can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Example Data:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (city:City) ASSERT city.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (state:State) ASSERT state.name IS UNIQUE;

MERGE (pb:City {name: 'Paderborn'}) 
MERGE (state1:State {name: 'Bavaria'})
MERGE (state2:State {name: 'North Rhine-Westphalia'}) 
MERGE (pb)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(state1);
```

The following statement will remove the existing relationship and create a new one:

```
MATCH (n { name: "Paderborn"})-[r]->(), (state {name: "Bavaria"})
MERGE (n)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(state)
DELETE r;
```